Keras siamese model history is empty
I am making a siamese neural network with triplet loss using keras, and have encountered an odd problem. I tried saving my history twice: once in a callback (saved as a dictionary), and once after training with model.fit(), using pickle (saved as a history object). In both instances, the code runs smoothly, but afterwards the saved files are only several hundred bytes and when I plot them with matplotlib, the plot is empty.
Here's the callback I passed to model.fit():
class MetricsCallback(tensorflow.keras.callbacks.Callback):
 def init(self, train_data, validation_data, embedding_model, folder_path, file_name):
super(MetricsCallback, self).init() 
self.validation_data = validation_data 
self.train_data = train_data 
self.history={} 
self.embedding_model=embedding_model 
self.file_name = file_name 
self.folder_path = folder_path

def calc_metrics(self ,dataset):
  #for  accuracy
    y_true_acc=[]
    y_pred=[]

    #for auc-roc and eer
    y_true=[]
    y_scores=[]

    for triplet in dataset: #dataset is train_data or validation_data
      anchor, positive, negative = triplet #get the anchor, posotive and negative tensors from each triplet tuple
      a_emb=embedding_model(np.expand_dims(anchor, axis=0)) #get the embeddings for each
      p_emb=embedding_model(np.expand_dims(positive, axis=0))
      n_emb=embedding_model(np.expand_dims(negative, axis=0))

      dist_p = np.linalg.norm(a_emb - p_emb) #calculate distances
      dist_n = np.linalg.norm(a_emb - n_emb)
      #for triplet acc:
      y_true_acc. append(1) #the true label is always 1
      if dist_p +alpha<dist_n : #accurate
        y_pred.append(1)
      else:
        y_pred.append(0)

      #for auc-roc and eer:
      y_true.append(0) #for a-p
      y_true.append(1) #for a-n

      y_scores.append(1-dist_p)#if it's small like we want, it gets a high score
      y_scores.append(dist_n)# if it's big like we want, it gets a high score

    #compute acc:
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true_acc, y_pred)
    #compute auc-roc and eer:
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_scores)
    auc_roc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    eer = 1 - max(tpr - fpr)

    return accuracy, auc_roc, eer, fpr, tpr

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    # Compute metrics on train data
    loss_train = logs.get('loss')
    accuracy_train , auc_roc_train, eer_train, fpr_train, tpr_train= self.calc_metrics(self.train_data)

    self.history['train_loss'] = loss_train
    self.history['train_accuracy'] = accuracy_train
    self.history['train_auc_roc'] = auc_roc_train
    self.history['train_eer'] = eer_train
    self.history['train_fpr'] = fpr_train
    self.history['train_tpr'] = tpr_train

    # Log the metrics
    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1} - Train Loss: {loss_train}, Accuracy: {accuracy_train}, AUC-ROC: {auc_roc_train}, EER: {eer_train}')

    # Compute metrics on validation data
    loss_val = logs.get('val_loss')

    accuracy_val, auc_roc_val, eer_val, fpr_val, tpr_val= self.calc_metrics(self.validation_data)

    self.history['val_loss'] = loss_val
    self.history['val_accuracy'] = accuracy_val
    self.history['val_auc_roc'] = auc_roc_val
    self.history['val_eer'] = eer_val
    self.history['val_fpr'] = fpr_val
    self.history['val_tpr'] = tpr_val

    # Log the metrics
    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1} - Validation Loss: {loss_val},  Accuracy: {accuracy_val}, AUC-ROC: {auc_roc_val}, EER: {eer_val}')

    # Save the metric history to Google Drive
    epoch_number = epoch + 1  # Epoch starts from 0, so we add 1 to get the actual epoch number
    file_name_with_epoch = f"{self.file_name}_epoch_{epoch_number}.pkl"
    file_path = os.path.join(self.folder_path, file_name_with_epoch)
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file_pi:
        pickle.dump(self.history, file_pi)
    print('saved metrics')

metrics_callback = MetricsCallback(train_set, val_set,simese_model_1,folder_path, file_name)

I tried just saving the history after training like this, but this too is empty:
with open('historyPath', 'wb') as file_pi: pickle.dump(history, file_pi)

I suspect this is because I have a custom loss (triplet loss) and custom metrics in the callback. However, this is the very reason I tried saving it in the custom callback.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks.
